# Pourquoi est-ce que l'adverbe « or(es) » s'accorde ?

Tags: orthographe, histoire, accord, adverbes

Ma recherche de l'adverbe « dorénavant » m'expose à cet adverbe soutenu « or » , mais je suis surpris car CNTRL.FR indique qu'il s'accorde en : [or, ore , or(e)(s)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/or).

Par exemple, ce site Web sur *dorénavant* cite « d'**or** en avant » et  « d'**ore** an avant ». En revanche, http://www.notrefamille.com/dictionnaire/definition/dorenavant ne cite que « d'**ores** en avant ».

Je constate l'illogisme des langues, mais comment expliquer cette désinence ? Mis à part les adverbes qui sont aussi des adjectifs, y en a-t-il d'autres qui s'accordent comme ceci ?

Answer (score 3):

Ce n'est pas une variation grammaticale mais bien orthographique. Ce mot (aujourd'hui virtuellement inconnu en dehors de l'expression *d'ores et déjà*) demeure invariable, mais il s'est écrit différemment au cours de l'histoire.

La variation entre *or* et *ore* (l'orthographe d'origine), selon le TLFi lui-même, "s'explique par le caractère accessoire du mot". Le "*s* adverbial", pour sa part est mal compris en français, mais on trouve [un bref commentaire ici](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/suf-s.html). Même Grevisse (*Le Bon Usage*, 14e éd., §960) ne fournit pas plus de détails que le fait que ce -s a été ajouté à un grand nombre de mots invariables au Moyen Âge, et de discuter de certains usages alternatifs qui se sont maintenus plus longtemps (généralement en poésie).